# What user is asp.net run under in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, asp.net, iis-7.5

When running a web application in an Application Pool with Integrated Mode in IIS 7.5 on Windows 7, what user account is ASP.NET running under?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever account is associated with the Application Pool.

Open the IIS manager, select the application pool and select "Advanced Settings". Under Process Model there is an Identity setting: this is the user.

IIS7.5 adds an inbuilt account "Application Identity" which is a per-application pool user dynamically created to run IIS applications (as Win7/2008R2 add per service users) to allow finer grained access control and additional process isolation.